# What does python slicing syntax [o:,:] mean

Tags: python, numpy

Just a small and probably very simple question. Someone gave me the following line of code:

```
im = axs[0,i].pcolormesh(imgX[o:,:], imgY[o:,:], img.mean(-1)[o:,:], cmap='Greys')
```

I know ":" means everything in that column or row (or array depth, depending on how you look at it). But what does "o:" mean?

Comment: That's numpy's ndarray slicing. `o` is some variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is *not* related to the usage, but shows how the operation "is parsed".

---

```
class X:
   def __getitem__(self, index):
       return index

X()[:,:]
>> (slice(None,None,None), slice(None,None,None))
```

And with different values for clarity:

```
X()[0, 1:, 3:4, 5:6:7]
>> (0, slice(1,None,None), slice(3,4,None), slice(5,6,7))
```

So, with that in mind `img[o:,:]` is like `img[o:, :]` is like

```
img.__getitem__( (slice(o,None,None), slice(None,None,None)) )
```

Comment: This answer needs more explanation. It shows what internal methods get invoked with what arguments, but not what the slice *means*. If I didn't already know how NumPy slicing works, I would not know what the slice in the question does after reading this answer.

Comment: @user2357112 I would encourage someone else to post an answer and steal the "accept vote" away, especially in context of numpy! This answer is the result of a wanting to share information that could not comfortably live in a comment; but alas, I myself do not use numpy.

Answer (score 2):

`o` is a variable like any other (but with a very bad name, as it can be confused with a zero).

`[o:, :]` means "all the elements from the first axis starting in the element `o`, and all in the second axis. In your particular case, the image will show only the rows from `o` to the bottom.

I want to add that in this case, you are getting a view, i.e., a reference to the original array, so the data is not actually copied.